# How can I load an HTML string into a Firemonkey TWebBrowser?

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control, firemonkey

I'm trying to use the Firemonkey `TWebBrowser` to load some HTML that is generated at runtime. The HTML is a Delphi string.

I've looked at some code from: http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2004/a/bltip0104_4.htm

```
procedure WBLoadHTML(WebBrowser: TWebBrowser; HTMLCode: string) ;
var
   sl: TStringList;
   ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
   WebBrowser.Navigate('about:blank') ;
   while WebBrowser.ReadyState < READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE do
     Application.ProcessMessages;

   if Assigned(WebBrowser.Document) then begin
     sl := TStringList.Create;
     try
       ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
       try
         sl.Text := HTMLCode;
         sl.SaveToStream(ms) ;
         ms.Seek(0, 0) ;
         (WebBrowser.Document as IPersistStreamInit).Load(TStreamAdapter.Create(ms)) ;
       finally
         ms.Free;
       end;
     finally
       sl.Free;
     end;
   end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject) ;
var
  sHTML : string;
begin
  sHTML := '<a href="http://delphi.about.com">GOTO</a>' +
           '<b>About Delphi Programming</b>';
  WBLoadHTML(WebBrowser1,sHTML) ;
end;
```

but this appears to be designed for a VCL application which is incompatible with Firemonkey `TWebBrowser`.

How can I achieve the same thing as this code example but using the Firemonkey control?

Comment: You're targeting mobile?  There's no TWebBrowser available for Firemonkey in desktop apps.

Comment: I'm targeting both mobile and desktop. I thought FMX was supposed to be cross-platform?

Comment: It is cross-platform, but you there's no FMX TWebBrowser component targeted at Desktop apps.  Only Mobile.  You'll need to use a different component at the presentation end if you want to create an FMX desktop application.

Answer (score 1):

Use WebBrowser LoadFromStrings Method.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this functionality in a DLL...detail and [downloadable example here](http://www.delphipraxis.net/1248435-post8.html).

Another option is to consider this [open-source TWebBrowserEx project](https://github.com/freeonterminate/delphi/tree/master/TWebBrowser). It actually will use the platform's normal web browser functionality. However, in the case of Windows it means that in your FMX project you will be using the VCL for the web browser support..**.which may or may not have unintended effects.**

> This class provide WebBrowser for All-Platform FireMonkey
>   Applications.

Platform => Component

- Windows => **IWebBrowser(IE)**
- OS X => **WebView(Safari)**
- iOS => **WebView**
- Android  => **WebView**